# In Core Data, how can I check if error was caused by "disk is full"?

Tags: ios, core-data

I just like to ask whether I can check if error on Core Data was caused by full disk. I saw in developer site that "disk is full" can be checked from the exception description but I do not have an idea on how to check it. Is `NSPersistentStoreIncompleteSaveError` the error I need to catch?

Reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingPersistentStores.html

Answer (score -1):

I think, you should find that error in save: on MOC. See [Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/save%3a).